# how can I disable the console tty0?

Tags: linux, console, serial-port, tty

I have an old laptop that has a serial RS232 port. I installed Debian in this machine to learn how to use linux. One of the things I want to do is to receive and send text via the physical com port that my laptop has but I have a problem.

When I open the gtkterm it says **Cannot open /dev/ttyS0 : Permission denied**. Then, at the console I typed **dmesg | grep tty** and it shows this:

> [   0.000000] console [tty0] enabled

Can anyone tell me how can I disable the console in order to be able to use the physical serial com port [tty0] with the gtkterm to send and receive text to a hardware device?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if use without `sudo`  you will receive Cannot open `/dev/ttyS0: Permission denied`

above error message.

So try `sudo gtkterm` . the above problem will be solved.